# What js function to use for toggle sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to use css (or) js to show/hide my blogger sidebar.

i have button: .toogle-button
and sidebar: .sidebar

What is the best option to make my sidebar show/hide when visitor click on button?

You can see site live, waiting to add this funtion at [here](http://detelin-markov.blogspot.com)
sidebar is now display:none

Suggest code please?

Here is part of my code and js that i try to run:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(.sidebar-toggle).click(function(){
            $(.sidebar-open).slideToggle(slow);
            $(this).toggleClass(active); return false;
            }); 
            });


<button aria-expanded="false" class="sidebar-toggle" style="height: 72px;"><span class="screen-reader-text">Toggle Sidebar</span></button>
```

And i have 2 css class for sidebar
.sidebar - display: none
.sidebar-open - display:block

Comment: Atleast share relevant HTML. Even pseudo code will do

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works. You have to make some searches, try by yourself, and come here get help if you're stuck, by sharing your code.

Comment: .on() / .toggle()... make some searches...

Comment: i Try several js but don`t work. May be i don`t understend what exactly make code that i use.

Comment: @satpal i add part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your selector in quotes.

*Use*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sidebar-toggle").click(function() {
        $(".sidebar-open").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Currently, there is console error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Comment: I remove all js from code but console again show errors... Thanks for js i will try to find out where is console problem.